# Android Studio 2.2: gradle sync very slow

Tags: android-studio

i find that AS 2.2 preview 3 and 4 are very slow when doing gradle sync.

i have `classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:2.1.2'` and `distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.14-all.zip`.

the gradle sync always takes more than 1 hour. what's more, when the sync finished and i restart AS so that sync is started again, the sync is slow again: the sync is slow every time i start AS...

my PC has: i7-6700, 16G RAM, 512G SSD.

when i use AS 2.1.1 for the same project, the gradle sync is very fast, about 1-3 minutes.

it is a bug, or because my project has 12 necessary modules, or is there some workaround?

Comment: it depends on your modules as well as on your development hardware machine. See is there some malware that is using your cpu which make gradle to take longer time to run a build. Also try removing any new software that you installed.

Comment: plz refer to my edit.

Comment: Try invalidating cache and restart android studio. This will clear gradle old files.

Comment: @devprashant unfortunately, the gradle sync with AS 2.2 is slow even if i `git clone` to get a brand fresh project repo...

Comment: First delete gradlew from android project . Then gradle and .gradle folders but not build.gradle. Try again invalidating cache and restart android studio.

Comment: @devprashant i'll have a try when i'm home. i've AS 2.1.2 in my corp working environment... thanks~

Comment: i file a bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=214308.

Answer (score 2):

Android Studio 2.2 Preview 4 is extremely slow and buggy.
I use it on macbook pro 15 i7, 256 ssd and 16gb, and sometime the memory usage is up to 90% (no other apps running).
I rolled back to the stable channel and it's back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

I also updated Android Studio2.2 Stabled, but it's obviously slower than previous version.